# Attribute Index doesn't work in GeoMesa HBase

Tags: hbase, geomesa

I tried to store some data in Geomesa HBase cluster without spatial index. The table schema is as below. However I was not able to query data with attribute index (in this case the "nodeId" column). The export command I used is: `geomesa-hbase export -c atlas -f OSMWayNodesTest3 -m 10 -q "nodeId='node1'"` and `geomesa-hbase export -c atlas -f OSMWayNodesTest3 -q "nodeId = 'node1'" --hints QUERY_INDEX=attr:8:nodeId`. However I was able to get data if I enforced it to use ID index like `geomesa-hbase export -c atlas -f OSMWayNodesTest3 -q "nodeId = 'node1'" --hints QUERY_INDEX=id`. So attribute index doesn't work here but ID index does.

**Table Schema**

```
INFO  Describing attributes of feature 'OSMWayNodesTest3'
wayId             | String
nodeId            | String (Attribute indexed)
serializerVersion | String
featurePayload    | String

User data:
  geomesa.ignore.dtg | true
  geomesa.indices    | id:4:3:,attr:8:3:nodeId
```

**Data in the table**

```
[hadoop@ip-10-0-17-152 ~]$ geomesa-hbase export -c atlas -f OSMWayNodesTest3 -m 2
id,wayId:String,nodeId:String,serializerVersion:String,featurePayload:String
64d9dc80973fa2e5174525c2bd8fc7f2,way2,node1,geojson,payload
8a87e576b1a1c03bc3d78caaef5b9fd0,way2,node2,geojson,payload
INFO  Feature export complete to standard out in 12825ms for 2 features
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a [ticket](https://geomesa.atlassian.net/browse/GEOMESA-2733) in the GeoMesa JIRA to track the issue. As a work-around, if you have a date or geometry type field in your schema, it will return queries correctly.